# Mongodb plugin for cakephp 2.10 which will work on php7.4

Tags: mongodb, cakephp, php-7.4

my old application was on cakephp2.5 , php 5.6 mongodb [ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb), i have updated it to cakephp2.10 and php7.4 but this plugin is not working as new php-mongodb driver is not supporting to it. is there any other plugin which will work on cakephp2.5 or is there any other way to make it work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have found workaround for it Mongo PHP Adapter

The Mongo PHP Adapter is a userland library designed to act as an adapter
between applications relying on ext-mongo and the new driver (`ext-mongodb`).

It provides the API of ext-mongo built on top of mongo-php-library, thus being
compatible with PHP 7.

## Goal

This library aims to provide a compatibility layer for applications that rely on
libraries using ext-mongo, e.g.
[Doctrine MongoDB ODM](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm), but want to
migrate to PHP 7 on which `ext-mongo` will not run.

You should not be using this library if you do not rely on a library using
`ext-mongo`. If you are starting a new project, please check out
[mongodb/mongodb](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library).